# DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

This error happens when I use the `SelectedItem.Text` of a dropdownlist as a value to pass for ObjectDataSource.
Here is the markup

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsInsert" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetStudentInClass2" TypeName="MIHE_MIS.DALS.MidTermExamResultDAL">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter DefaultValue="" ControlID="ddlClasses" Name="classCode" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSemesters" Name="semesterID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSpecialization" Name="specializationID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Moreover, I add the `Select Class` text the dropdownlist dynamically.

```
protected void ddlClasses_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItem list = new ListItem("Select Class", "-1");
            this.ddlClasses.Items.Insert(0, list);
        }
```

Comment: Your `PropertyName` should be just `Text`, not a property. The binder doesn't understand sub properties

Comment: I have the ClassID which is an integer as the Value of dropdownlist

Comment: I have mistyped that. actually that is SelectedItem.Text

Comment: Yes but you still can't bind to a sub-property of `SelectedValue`. It needs to be a top-level property

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the markup for `semesterID`, it's binding to `SelectedValue` which is expected to be `Int32`. If you now look at the markup for `classCode`, you're binding to `SelectedValue.Text` on the same object. We know from the first instance that `SelectedValue` is `Int32` which doesn't have a property called `Text`. You'll need to correct your binding to the correct object and property type.

Based on the code above, the `ObjectDataSource` will not be able to pick out the text from `SelectedItem.Text`. In order to get around this, you need to modify the `ObjectDataSource` to have a `Selecting` event like so;

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsInsert" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetStudentInClass2" 
                      TypeName="MIHE_MIS.DALS.MidTermExamResultDAL"
                      OnSelecting="odsInsert_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="classCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSemesters" Name="semesterID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSpecialization" Name="specializationID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Then in your code behind you'd have the event declared;

```
protected void odsInsert_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["classCode"] = ddlClasses.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: The error is gone but problem still exist. I get no data and that is because of the SelectedItem.Text the objectdataSource can't get the SelectedItem.Text

Comment: You'll need to hook into the `ObjectDataSource`'s `Selecting` event and supply the parameter programatically. You can't bind direct in the manner you need.

Comment: @ElhamKohestani, I've updated my answer with how to supply `SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: It is not working. I  changed the datasource to a DataTable it worked well but with objectDataSource it is not working don't know. :(

Comment: @ElhamKohestani What part is not working? I actually based the code sample above on code we have in production - it should work. What are you seeing?

Comment: The object datasource does not contain data hence there is no record in the gridview

Comment: Is the `Selecting` event being hit? Is it triggered after the `DataBound` event (I'm assuming your DDL is also bound)?

Comment: The select event is being hit too but still not working

Comment: And is there a value in `ddlClasses.SelectedItem.Text` at that moment in time?

Comment: OK, but if you execute `GetStudentInClass2` in SQL Management Studio and supply it with the same parameters, what do you get? It sounds like the selected parameters don't pick out a student which is why your grid is empty

Comment: The query works fine and it works when I return the result of that query in a DataTable

Comment: @ElhamKohestani Something about the parameters is not set up right and causing the result set to be empty. You'll have to track down what and make sure that the parameters are correct. Without being able to see your full set of code, I cannot see what's going on